# Import distinct records in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, insert, duplicates, distinct

I receive a daily CSV with duplicate records in it.  I tried to import it using BULK INSERT, but my primary key constraint throws me an error because of the duplicates.

To fix this, I am thinking about importing the data into a new table with no primary key constraint, and then using the following code:

```
INSERT INTO final_table(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3
FROM temporary_table
```

Is this the best way of going about this? Or is there an easier way to do this in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: What would you like to do with the duplicates? remove them or ignore them?

Comment: I would suggest BCP'ing them to a table, with out an index, then adding an index with a IGNORE_DUP_KEY set accordingly

Comment: I'd like to completely remove them.  The staging table method seems to be working so far.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "new" table is called the staging table. It should have very little limitations... ie. constraints.  Once loaded there, you scrub and load into your "final" table.

I think what you're proposing to do is the simplest. Unless you're using SSIS and you're adamant about not using a staging table.  I generally like having a staging table around so I can see an exact replica of the file if something were to go wrong.  Helps with troubleshooting.

Comment: Does the staging table have to be a real table, or can I use a temp table?

Comment: well, technically #tmp tables are tables residing in the tempdb.  However, it's session specific so you can "create table #tmp" before bulkinserting.

Comment: I generally like have a staging table that persist in my ETL process.  Just so I have access to the raw data.  However, in this scenario it doesn't matter as much since you're just trying to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: I work in Oracle and this is the basic approach I use. I use a staging table to load all the data into (using a fast loader utility) and then I take it from there and process it via a stored procedure. This is a universal approach (I'd do this with MySQL, PostGres, DB2, SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO final_table
SELECT DISTINCT csv.*
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Text1.csv', SINGLE_CLOB) AS csv
```

Comment: I get the following error:
The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

That is when I try to run the following code:
INSERT INTO final_table(col1,col2,col3)
SELECT DISTINCT csv.*
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Text1.csv', SINGLE_CLOB) AS csv

Should I be mentioning the comma delimiter somewhere for the CSV?

Comment: I wrote the code the way you can understand, you have to specify the columns in the select that matches the table definition of the final_table.

Comment: How can you define the columns in the "csv" table?  Aren't we are inserting directly from a file?  I specified the columns for final_table like final_table(col1, col2, col3)

Comment: You can define the columns for csv in the format file: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx)

Comment: Great info.  Thanks.  I think I will try the staging table first and then give this a shot if that doesn't work out.